# ArrayList of generic objects in java. Unchecked call to 'Class(T)' as a member of raw type 'Class'

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following piece of code:

```
public class Coordinate<T>{
T coordinate;
//rest of class
}
```

and then i later try to create an ArrayList which contains various Coordinates like so:

```
ArrayList<Coordinate> location = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
```

and finally i add some coordinates to the location

```
location.add(new Coordinate(0));
location.add(new Coordinate("A"));
location.add(new Coordinate(0.1f));
```

these location.add() calls gives me the following warning:

> Unchecked call to 'Coordinate(T)' as a member of raw type 'Coordinate'

I have searched for this warning and found some hits, but i was not able to figure out from those answers how i could make my application work, because i would like the ArrayList location to be able to hold different types of Coordinates, so i cant do something like

`ArrayList<Coordinate<Integer>> location = new ArrayList<Coordinate<Integer>>();`.

Perhaps I'm just going about the problem in the wrong way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `List<Coordinate<?>>`

Comment: Because your ArrayList of Coordinate objects can have Numbers and Strings, you can declare it as 

`ArrayList<Coordinate<Object>> location = new ArrayList<Coordinate<Object>>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to mix just numbers the following can be used (`<>` is the diamond from Java 7 and onwards, for earlier versions there is no type inference).

```
List<Coordinate<? extends Number>> location = new ArrayList<>();
location.add(new Coordinate<>(1));
location.add(new Coordinate<>(1.0));
```

If you want to use *all sorts of Objects* the following can be used:

```
List<Coordinate<?>> location = new ArrayList<>();
location.add(new Coordinate<>(1));
location.add(new Coordinate<>("Hello"));
```

Since you created the `Coordinate` object without the generic parameter you got the warning.

```
new Coordinate(0) -> Unchecked call to 'Coordinate(T)' as a member of raw type 'Coordinate'
```

By changing the creation of `Coordinate` to `new Coordinate<>(1)` or whatever type is needed you avoid that problem.

Answer (score 0):

In you array list you are putting `Number` as well as `String`.

i.e. you are adding objects in your array list, so its type should be `Object`

Because it is `parent` of all the classes in java.

```
List<Coordinate<Object>> location = new ArrayList<Coordinate<Object>>();
```